# Why mongoDb sort not working?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongo-shell

I am having a db, having 3000 values and each value contains approx 10 fields, now when i try to sort the values by a particular field, it only sort up to a limit and shows a value. 
Like here in Robomongo i am trying to sort a value named NET_TURNOV which you can see in photo 9990
The command which i have used is:

```
db.getCollection('col').find({}).sort({"NET_TURNOV": -1})
```

[image: sorting by NET_TURNOV]

However, in this next photo you can see the same db having higher value of NET_TURNOV, why this is happening.
here is the next photo
[image]

Comment: Yes, i guess when i click on view document in robomongo it shows me the value in "NET_TURNOV":"xxxx"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your NET_TURNOV (and all other numbers) are stored as strings. This explains the "weird" sorting.

Number `22` is greater than number `9`, but *string* `"22"` is less than string `"9"` (because they're compared character by character).

Numbers should be stored as numbers, if you want to do any number-y stuff on them, like sorting, or finding maximum, or adding/subtracting them, etc. Which is to say "always".

Comment: Wow, thanks, however, if there is no option to store as number, how can i sort it then.

Comment: @AlpitAnand: then you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot, i think i have to recode to build my DB from scratch

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the field `timestamp` was a number `double` but somehow Mongo was interpreting it as a string. I don't know why but after upgrading from Mongo 3.2 to 3.4 this disappeared.

UPDATE

Okay, so I have finally nailed it!

WRONG

```
model.find({query},function(err, docs){
    //docs sorted on OSX but not on Ubuntu
    //documents are listed before the sorting happens
}).sort('timestamp');
```

CORRECT

```
model.find({query})
.sort('timestamp')
.exec(function(err, docs){
   //docs sorted on both systems
});
```

CORRECT

```
model.find({query})
.sort('timestamp')
.then(function(docs){
   //docs in right order
})
.catch(function(error){});
```

Comment: i did not find anything different by adding ,exec